# R equivalent to the Python function "dir"?

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that can tell me the attributes of a given object (or class)?

Consider the "dir" function in python when passed the `file` class:

```
>>> dir(file)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', 
 '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed',
 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name',
 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines',
 'seek', 'soft space', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines',
 'xreadlines']
```

Maybe there is an equivalent of `type` as well(?)

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

R makes several different object oriented systems available to you, so if you don't know what species of object you're dealing with, you'll first need to determine whether it is one of S3, S4, or RC. Use `isS4(x)` and `is(x, 'refClass')` for this. If it's not S4 and not RC, it's S3. See [Hadley's Advanced R chapter on object oriented programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#rc) for more information.

For S3 and S4 objects there are several functions you need to call to get information equivalent to Python's `dir`. All of these methods will require you to supply the name of the class of the object as an argument, which you can determine with the `class` function.

For methods, use `methods(class=class(x))` for S3 objects and `showMethods(class=class(x))` for S4 objects. To reveal "attribute" names/values, use `attributes(x)` for S3 objects and `getSlots(class(x))` for S4 objects. Note, `getSlots` will only show the slot names and types, not their values. To access the values, you'll have to use `slot`, but these values should also print when you simply print the object to the console.

Comment: is there a way to tell the components of a package the same way you can check the components of a module using Python's `dir`?